# How to resize partition that is inside "Linux LVM" partition

Tags: 13.10, gparted, lvm, partitioning, resize

How to resize partition that is inside "Linux LVM" partition in 13.10 Ubuntu? I transferred Ubuntu installation from 160GB to 500GB disk. I have successfully resized sda3 partition using Ubuntu LiveCd and GParted and now have no idea how to resize this "155 GB Block Device". 
Here is how it looks like.

[image: Screenshot GParted and Disks]

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GParted is useless for this. You'll need to either use an assortment of text-mode tools (such as `resize2fs` and `lvresize`) or another GUI front-end, such as `kvpm` or `system-config-lvm`. I believe that both are available in the Ubuntu repositories. [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-resizing-partitions-2/index.html) I wrote a while back goes into a bit more detail, but stops short of being a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: It was done with just a few clicks in kvpm. Thanks!

Comment: Note, `kvpm` is a kde-based tool. If you are on a gnome based system I think I would suggest using `system-config-lvm`. Additionally I find kvpm to be a bit cluttered and hard to read comparatively.

Comment: An update: GParted has begun adding LVM capabilities. It's now possible to resize physical volumes (partitions used by KVM), but AFAIK, it's still impossible to resize logical volumes with GParted. I don't know if the GParted developers plan to add support for resizing logical volumes in the future.

Comment: @ThorSummoner: looks like [`system-config-lvm` is no longer maintained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968297/is-there-a-new-gui-for-lvm).