# how to manage mirror legs and stripes in graphical way now w/o KVPM on 20.04?

Tags: lvm

On ubuntu 18.04, I used KVPM.
Now that it is gone on 20.04, I am trying to use "KDE partition manager" but I can find no way to manage my existing mirror legs, to create new ones, neither to create stripes...

So, how to I manage it on 20.04 now that KVPM is gone?
Is there some graphical alternative, or even a text mode one that does things as well as KVPM did?

KDE partition manager can even list the groups but the information is quite incomplete, there is nothing about mirror legs and stripes :(

Answer (score 3):

Just as a test, I installed these packages from 18.04:

liblvm2app2.2_2.02.176-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.3_amd64.deb, the deb link from downloadable files at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/liblvm2app2.2/2.02.176-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.3

kvpm_0.9.10-1.1_amd64.deb, the deb link from downloadable files at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/kvpm/0.9.10-1.1

initially I didnt think they would even install, now KVPM is running in ubuntu 20.04!
It is working very fine, just created a mirror leg to my root filesystem!

TIP: if you need to modify the filesystem label (that is mounted at /media/$USER/TheLabel) you can use the Disks application and then click on the gears and choose "edit partition" as the only thing you can do there is change the label :)

Comment: related, but newer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296095/how-can-i-install-kvpm-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts