# How can I install KVPM on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: package-management, lvm

Have read references to KVPM in some questions about resizing LVs. Tried the typical `sudo apt install kvpm` but it gave me a message `unable to locate package`. I have checked the box for every source available on Software & Updates. Then I downloaded a deb package from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kvpm/kvpm_0.9.10-1.1_amd64.deb and got the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kvpm : Depends: liblvm2app2.2 (>= 2.02.176) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get dependencies with it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/liblvm2app2.2_2.02.176-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install lvm2 ./liblvm2app2.2_2.02.176-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.3_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kvpm/kvpm_0.9.10-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./kvpm_0.9.10-1.1_amd64.deb
```

and then enjoy the KVPM application running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Depending on your desktop environment you can run it using one of the below commands:

- `sudo kvpm`
- `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY kvpm`

Comment: I'll give it a try. Can I ask if you have any perspective on the comment above about KVPM being for kUbuntu and not Ubuntu? Would it work as well on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install?

Comment: The above method is universal, it uses packages from repository. I have tested in on fresh 20.04 LTS virtual machine. So it should work on your system.

Comment: This worked up until I tried to create a logical volume or pool. Then I got an error "Executable: 'lvcreate' not found. Doing `sudo apt-get -y install lvm2` seems to have fixed it. @N0rbert

Comment: didn't work for me. `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.`

Comment: See update above @SridharSarnobat .

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now I get: `polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie` (note I'm using `ssh -Y`; I also tried in an `xrdp` session)

Comment: Probably you have to use local GUI or CLI tool.

Answer (score 0):

- `dpkg` does not solve depedencies.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: kvpm : Depends: liblvm2app2.2 (>= 2.02.176) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Means you need to install `liblvm2app2.2` but that will likely report another dependency.

Are your SURE you want KVPM? **KDE** Volume Partition Manager is for kUbuntu. Not Ubuntu. In Ubuntu resizing LV can already be done from within the "disks" utility.
See [Manage volumes and partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-partitions.html.en). Next: that software is ONLY available for 16.04 and [18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kvpm).  Are you sure you want to use software for managing volumes that is at least 2 years old?

If you want to use something from the Ubuntu packages I would assume you would want to install [partitionmanager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/partitionmanager) but I still have questions ...

> **View and manage volumes and partitions using the disk utility**
>
> You can check and modify your computer’s storage volumes with the disk utility.
>
> Open the Activities overview and start Disks.
>
> - In the list of storage devices on the left, you will find hard disks, CD/DVD drives, and other physical devices. Click the device you want to inspect.
> - The right pane provides a visual breakdown of the volumes and partitions present on the selected device. It also contains a variety of tools used to manage these volumes.
>
> **Be careful: it is possible to completely erase the data on your disk with these utilities.**

- Head the warning. Make sure you have a backup of at least your personal data and know how to restore it.

So it seems it is already available? Why does that not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I booted through a live USB and tried using the Disks utility to resize my LV but the option is greyed out for both the root and swap partition. To you give some background, I am trying to increase size of my swap partition that was created by default installation. I understand there are CLI alternatives available but want to see if I can figure out a way to do that in GUI first. I'm an absolute noob when it comes to Linux / Ubuntu. About your comment on KVPM is for kUbuntu - does that mean it won't work as well on Ubuntu?

Comment: Forgot to add, I tried partition manager as well. It is able to detect LV when I run it from my machine, but when I run it from a live USB, it's not able to recognize the encrypted LV. Couldn't figure out a way to unlock it like you can do on Disks.

Comment: gnome-disks doesn't seem to have any volume management capabilities from what I can see.