# GUI for LVM management on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I've seen [Is there a new GUI for LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968297/is-there-a-new-gui-for-lvm) from 5 years ago but none of the answers seem applicable to Ubuntu 22.04.

I've created a 2-disk RAID and put an LVM2 physical volume on top, then created a volume group containing a logical volume into which I've put a filesystem.  The problem I have is that the disk manager doesn't show anything beyond the partitions, making it difficult to manage them as the command line is a bit obscure for me.

Is there a better GUI than this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The fundamental question is "Is there a better GUI?"

Answer (score 0):

Webmin  has dedicated modules for LVM and Raid with an easy to use GUI.
If you are more interested in functionalities and "easy to use" than "visual" it could be an option.

[https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Logical_Volume_Management#:~:text=Webmin's%20Logical%20Volume%20Manager%20module,their%20physical%20and%20logical%20volumes](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Logical_Volume_Management#:%7E:text=Webmin%27s%20Logical%20Volume%20Manager%20module,their%20physical%20and%20logical%20volumes).

https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Linux_RAID

Answer (score 0):

I've been using KDE partition manager sucessfully